# What happens when I import a JS file into another JS file?

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have the following file.

**file.js**

```
import Package from 'package';

Package.method();
```

**main.js**

When I import `file.js` into `main.js` in the following manner...

```
import './file';

Package.someOtherMethod();
```

Is it the equivalent to having the below in `main.js`?

```
import Package from 'package';

Package.method();

Package.someOtherMethod();
```

That is, can I think of importing a JS file using `import './file';` as just inserting code into `main.js`?

Comment: Using `import` will run the file and return the exports or just return the exports if the file has already been run.

Comment: `Package` is undefined in your main.js file. Modules have a separated name space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it the equivalent to having the below in `main.js`?

Not really. Importing from `"./file"` does mean that any of `"./file"`'s dependencies are loaded, which (in this case) means `"package"` is loaded, which means that its top-level code will be run (`Package.method()`). And that will happen before `main.js`'s top-level code is run (barring cyclical relationships). But it's not as though the source had been lifted out of `"./file"` and pasted into `main.js`. In particular, if *another* file also imports from `"./file"`, its top-level module code is **not** run a second time.

Lin Clark has a good article about module loading [here](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2018/03/es-modules-a-cartoon-deep-dive/), including a discussion of the three phases of module loading (Parsing, Instantiation, and Evaluation) and how cyclical relationships are handled.